# Set X-Auth-Token header in http connection endpoint in WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, authentication, header, wso2, esb

I'm new in WSO2 esb and for beginning i want to make a http connection to my external REST API.
This API is authenticated with X-Auth-Token header and its value.
I have tried to set this with header mediators but i don't know how do it.
If i set Header name: X-Auth-Token and value literal: w2441sdcxvcp2 I obtain below exception when deploy:

> Invalid SOAP header: X-Auth-Token specified at the header mediator.
>   All SOAP headers must be namespace qualified.

Has someone any idea or suggestion?
Thanks

This is the code of my proxy:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Proxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <header name="X-Auth-Token" scope="default" value="9a417d9d-712f-4eaf-ad38-7352394cea62"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="TokenSMS"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Now I no longer have the error but when send mediators call the API the authentication fails (how when no header has setted).

Comment: What was your header mediator configuration?

Comment: i have updated the firs post. Is there a method to watch the sent http request?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to watch what happens:
enable trace on your proxy:

and check your trace logs on:
esb_home\repository\logs\wso2-esb-trace.log
cheers